# How to create Entanglement, Superposition and interference?

Tags: python, algorithm, temenos-quantum, qiskit

I am looking the way How to create Entanglement, Superposition and interference? Can someone help to show how to code in qiskit? and the docs related to these mentioned above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
from qiskit import *  # importing qiskit
# instead of importing everything you could import things separately

def circ_superposition(number):

    # raising errors
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except:
        return "Number must be an integer"
    circ = QuantumCircuit(number, number)  # creating the circuit

    for i in range(number):
        circ.h(i)

    return circ
```

You might want to use the below to see the circuit

```
print(f'{circ_superposition(6)}') # add any integer in place of 6
```

and to create entanglement do the following

```
entanglement = QuantumCircuit(n, n)  # replace n by any integer
# apply h gates the qubits
for i in range(n): # replace n by any integer
    entanglment.h(i)
# apply cx gate
entanglement.cx(control, target) # replace control and target by control qubit and target qubit respectively
```

from further assistance refer to:
[Circuit Basics](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/01_circuit_basics.html)
And [Getting Stared With Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/1_getting_started_with_qiskit.html)

Also consider visiting:
[Super Dense Coding](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/superdense-coding.html) And [Quantum Teleportation](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html) for applications of Quantum Interference.